# Electron.js: addEventListener() doesn't work and I'm not getting any error

Tags: javascript, electron, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make an `Electron` app. I tried to add an event listener on a button for clicks in the `renderer` process, but nothing happens when I click the button. I am not getting any error.

**html**

```
<script src="event.js"></script>
<header>
  <button type="button" class="quit-button">Quit</button>
</header>
```

**js**

```
const {remote} = require('electron');
button = document.getElementById('quit-button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('quit');
  remote.app.quit();
});
```

Comment: Please define "_not working_". What you expect your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: Are you getting the console message?

Comment: Why are you iterating through with just one button?

Comment: Does it find any buttons? Does the event trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the HTML. The `<script>` must be after the `<button>`, otherwise the javascript runs before the button is created.

```html
 <body>
    <header>
        <button class="quit-button">Quit</button>
    </header>
    <script src="event.js"></script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your `<button>` tag into the `<body>` tag.

The button tag is not allowed in the head. When I moved the button to the body, it worked perfectly.

Comment: It it weren't in the body could he even see the button to click on it?

Comment: `<header>` is not `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

The way to import and close the app is not done right. You should do it as follows:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote
let qbutton = document.getElementsByClassName('quit-button');

for (var i = 0; i < qbutton.length; i++) {
     qbutton[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
          console.log('quit');
          remote.getCurrentWindow().close()
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is resolved. The problem was in the html. The `<script>` was before the `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one button, then:

```
const remote = require('electron');
qbutton = document.getElementsByClassName('quit-button')[0];

qbutton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('quit');
  remote.app.quit();
});
```

You don’t need any iteration.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is resolved. The problem was in the html. The `<script>` was before the `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer space)*.

The problem is resolved. The problem was in the HTML, I put the `<script>` before the `<button>`. Yeah, silly mistake!